# Replace Array.prototype.includes() with a method that does not return a boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a function in Typescript in which, from a string, it returns the key of the object that contains that variable.

I'm using `Array.prototype.includes()` to check that the variable exists, this can return `true` or `false`, so typing the resulting variable as a `string` gives me a typing error.

This is the error:

```
Type 'unknown' cannot be assigned to type 'string'
```

This is my function:

```
let testData = {
  data1: ['CAR','PLANE'],
  data2: ['COUNTRY','CITY']
};

let asset = 'car';

function resKey(asset) {

  let res = Object.keys(testData).find(key => {
    const value = testData[key]
  
    return value.includes(asset.toUpperCase())
  })

  return res

}

console.log(resKey(asset));
```

I'm only going to pass it values that are in the object, so I don't need to check if it exists.

**My problem**: how can I modify the function so that it only returns the key without the need to check if it exists?

Comment: You need to check which value array includes the asset to know which key to return. It looks like just a typescript typing issue. `let testData: Record<string, string[]> = {...` and `function resKey(asset: string)` gives typescript enough information to stop complaining.

Comment: [TSPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/w1yRXw)

Comment: Do not replace a prototype function. You can make a new function with a different name. It is highly frowned upon to overwrite default functionality of JavaScript. This can mess with and break other libraries.

Comment: @JeffB Who is overwriting a prototype function? I think the OP just means 'can i use a function other than `includes()`'

Comment: @pilchard I think the title/question has been updated, it no longer sounds that way, apologies! That or I am crazy and I blame Wednesdays.

Comment: @pilchard Correct, what I am looking for is the way to not pass through a boolean, but directly return the key of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments you can make your current function Typescript friendly by giving it some type annotations.

Alternatively you can avoid the `find()` by creating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the `testData` and just retrieving the `key` by `value` directly. Keep in mind that if there are duplicate values between different asset arrays this will return the key of the last instance (as opposed to `find()` which will return the key of the first instance).

```js
let testData = {
  data1: ['CAR', 'PLANE'],
  data2: ['COUNTRY', 'CITY']
};

let asset = 'car';

function resKey(asset) {
  const resMap = new Map(Object.entries(testData).flatMap(([k, v]) => v.map(a => [a, k])));
  
  return resMap.get(asset.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(resKey(asset));
```

To avoid creating a new `Map` on every call of the function you might employ a little currying.

```js
function resKeyFactory(data) {
  const resMap = new Map(
    Object.entries(data)
      .flatMap(([k, v]) => v.map(a => [a, k]))
  );

  return (asset) => resMap.get(asset.toUpperCase());
}

const
  testData = {
    data1: ['CAR', 'PLANE'],
    data2: ['COUNTRY', 'CITY']
  },
  asset = 'car',
  resKeyTestData = resKeyFactory(testData);

console.log(resKeyTestData(asset));
console.log(resKeyTestData('city'));
```

Typescript requires a high enough target to accept `flatMap` [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJqYgm).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries()` and `find()`.

```js
let testData = {
  data1: ['CAR', 'PLANE'],
  data2: ['COUNTRY', 'CITY']
};

function resKey(data, asset) {
  return Object.entries(data).find(([_, v]) => {
    return v.includes(asset.toUpperCase())
  })?.[0] || "no key found";
}

console.log(resKey(testData, "car"));
console.log(resKey(testData, "something"));
console.log(resKey(testData, "city"));
```

If you want to type, it would look something like this.

```
interface IData {
  data1: string[];
  data2: string[];
}

let testData: IData = {
  data1: ['CAR', 'PLANE'],
  data2: ['COUNTRY', 'CITY']
};

function resKey(data: IData, asset: string): string {
  return Object.entries(data).find(([_, v]) => {
    return v.includes(asset.toUpperCase())
  })?.[0] || "no key found";
}
```